# Top bar notifications (global inbox, +reputation) reset after refreshing or visiting another page

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, global-inbox, achievements-dialog

Normally, when you click the Inbox or the Achievements icon in the top bar, the notification (*x* new messages, +*y* reputation) clear. They still do, but upon refreshing the page, they're back to their old values.

[image]

It seems the counters have been reset a few minutes ago (my 'score' was 5 new messages and somewhere North of 100 reputation gained), but now they're back to a persistent 1 new message and +15 reputation. Unlike @Machavity I'm experiencing this on all sites, not just the ones which were down for maintenance earlier today.

Comment: Yup. And chat pings are really delayed. I usually get them within a minute and they're taking much longer, if they ever turn up.

Comment: They clear for me everywhere BUT Meta.SE and Meta.SO, which is what went down earlier

Comment: @Machavity strange, I'm experiencing it on all other sites as well (I checked half a dozen).

Comment: I'm also getting it on all sites I visit.

Comment: Ok, that was weird. Was on Space.SE with 0 notices showing when I had a notice come in and it said 3 (which is what I get on Meta.SE), not 1. Possibly related

Comment: Repro'd on MSO and SO

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This was an issue with a library update we just pushed out which *seemed* fine but depending on assembly load order created a race that exposed a binding redirect issue with `System.Numerics.Vectors` because the .NET assembly loader is just oh so fun.

The net result was this library which gets a first or second hit between Providence and StackExchange.Redis, when the latter was a binding victim (because it tried to load an older version, 4.1.3, which wasn't there and wasn't redirected). The build produced the latest 4.1.4 so when redis tried to load it had the secondary impact of falling back to a 5 second timeout cap. But, since we connect to many connections and secondaries for redundancy, this resulting in a 100+ second app startup stall (or a chance to have one rather).

[image: DLL diff]

In the end, this resulted in a terribly long startup time *and still no redis at the end* (**which is what caused this issue**), because the socket pipeline never started up.

The depth of library ref changes (transitive dependencies) here presented no issues or warnings for binding redirects in tooling (VS has a built-in warning for this...but it doesn't trigger) and only presented in prod and *only sometimes*. We deployed 2 tiers of servers and it wasn't until a follow-up build 20 minutes later that this issue started cropping up on app restarts *after the old app domains evacuated*.

Binding redirects are the devil. So we're moving to .NET Core where this crap doesn't happen.